# Ordenar lista por uma propriedade string com número

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda, order-by

Tenho um objeto do tipo `Ata` onde tenho a propriedade `NroAta` que corresponde ao número da Ata em questão, porém, no *grid* quando vou ordenar por este número, ele acaba por colocar os números em ordem errada. Ex.:

1, 10, 12, 2, 23, 3... e assim vai.

Criei um pseudo código do que estou utilizando para usar como exemplo:

```
List<Ata> lstAtas = new List<Ata>()
            {
                new Ata{ NroAta = "1"},
                new Ata{ NroAta = "10"},
                new Ata{ NroAta = "6"},
                new Ata{ NroAta = "4"},
                new Ata{ NroAta = "5"},
                new Ata{ NroAta = "2"},
                new Ata{ NroAta = "3"},
            };

            lstAtas = lstAtas.OrderBy(x => x.NroAta).ToList();

            foreach (var ata in lstAtas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", ata.NroAta);
            }
```

No exemplo, preciso que os números fiquem na ordem correta: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, utilizando do método `OrderBy`.

Comment: Você não está a ordenar números, está a ordenar strings(texto)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode garantir que é tudo número válido? Pode fazer isso:

```
lstAtas = lstAtas.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.NroAta)).ToList();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/lIAsDH). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cdbZZ9). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/OrderByProperty.cs).

Idealmente seria que um campo que claramente precisa ter números fosse numérico, aí seria simples.

Se manter como texto tem que usar algum truque. Outros podem ser aplicados ou convertendo para número ou manipulando o texto para normalizá-lo, usando [`PadLeft()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads) por exemplo, assim todos textos poderiam ter o mesmo tamanho e isso é importante para ordenar textos, já que a ordenação deste tipo é posicional.

Se for fazer uma comparação de dois textos grandes, ou de muitos pequenos, de tamanho diferente entre eles, fazer o *padding* gerará outro objeto já que C# usa *strings* imutáveis pode ser ineficiente. Para otimizar seria interessante criar um método de comparação ao contrário começando pelo fim. Isso ajuda por evitar a cópia dos dados e pressionar o GC. Pena que fazendo isso não poderá usar ponteiro para varrer o *array* de caracteres já que ele é privado. O ganho será limitado por causa disto. Precisaria testar se vale usar reflexão pelo menos se as *strings* forem grandes.

Comment: Não sei se posso garantir que sempre serão números válidos, terei que verificar. Mas a sua resposta já me ajudou, tanto no Convert pra Int quanto no PadLeft, não tinha pensado nisso.

Comment: Se não puder garantir, terá que ver o que pode ter e decidir como normalizar o dado, o `PadLeft()` pode resolver a maioria das situações.